# Why svn treats file and directory so differently?

Tags: svn, software-design

You can make two kinds of changes to your working copy: file changes and tree changes.
You don't need to tell Subversion that you intend to change a file;Subversion automatically detects which files have been changed, and in addition.For tree changes, you can ask Subversion to “mark” files and directories for scheduled removal, addition, copying, or moving.

Why doesn't svn treat directory the same way as it treats the file?

And after testing I find it quite practical to treat directory change the same way as file change since its last modify timestamp is  also track-able:

```
[ ~]# mkdir svntest
[ ~]# ll |grep svn
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 2011-04-10 07:41 svntest
[ ~]# touch svntest/demo.txt
[ ~]# ll |grep svn
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 2011-04-10 07:42 svntest
```

Comment: Last modification time in a directory is a irrelevant as it is in a file: version control systems track *content* changes. What exact problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are versioned all-or-nothing, while directories are versioned by item. If they were treated the same, there would be two different options:

- Treat files the same as directories: this means that each line in a file could be individually and you could choose which lines you want versioned. This doesn't make much sense.
- Treat directories as files: this means that each file you add to a directory is automatically added to your tree (even object files, binaries, and other temporaries), making it impossible to have a directory tree that differs from the trunk. This also doesn't seem too useful. Furthermore, the only way to handle renames without doing an immediate commit is to "schedule" it.

Comment: What do you mean by schedule here?

Comment: I used "schedule" in the same sense that it's used in the original question ("**scheduled** removal, addition, copying, or moving").

Comment: SVN's way of dealing with directory is causing lots of trouble for users,because we can edit files with `vi` directly,which makes a user think that he can `rm -rf directory` at his will,but that's not the truth!

Comment: @compile-fan: users can also think that they can `mv filename foo` or `rm filename`, or they'll be unaware of the `update` and `commit` commands. Reading the manual or receiving some basic training is always advisable.

Answer (score 0):

The best justification that I can find for not automatically marking all new files and directories for addition is that it's common to compile your code in the directory containing your working copy. If svn worked that way, the repository would end up filling up with a bunch of junk (the output from the compiler).